# Is there any way we can capture the client-side performance metrics through phantomjs by using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, phantomjs, performance-testing, client-side, jmeter-plugins

I tried configuring the "PhantonJS Driver Config"  in the JMeter(version 2.13) 
adding the following jar files under "`apache-jmeter2.13/lib/ext`" folder of JMeter and restarted.
But I could not see the config element under `ThreadGroup-->Add-->config element`

Throughout above PhantonJS Driver Config is there any way we can capture the following client-side performance metrics through phantomjs by using Jmeter 
DomLoad
windLoad
ResourceCount
Resource size.

Thanks

Shankar

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have two problems. First is related to showing up of PhantomJS Driver config element and second is for capturing client side performance. I would recommend opening separate questions with appropriate titles.

Comment: Yes thanks i have opened separate question for performance metrics collection.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37922398/collecting-client-side-performance-metrics-from-phantomjs-through-jmeter