# Collecting client side Performance Metrics from Phantomjs through Jmeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, phantomjs, jmeter-plugins

Throughout PhantonJS Driver Config is there any way we can capture the following client-side performance metrics through phantomjs by using Jmeter DomLoad windLoad ResourceCount Resource size.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend capturing the metrics using `WDS.browser.executeScript()` method which allows executing arbitrary JavaScript code. Once done you can directly store "interesting" values into JMeter Variables for later use.

Here is an example of using [Navigation API](http://w3c.github.io/navigation-timing/) to get extended information on page loading:

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('http://jmeter-plugins.org')
var timings = WDS.browser.executeScript('var performance = window.performance || window.webkitPerformance || window.mozPerformance || window.msPerformance || {}; var timings = performance.timing || {}; return timings;');
WDS.log.info(timings)
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

[image: JMeter WebDriver Navigation Timings]

See [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) guide for WebDriver Sampler tips and tricks

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for reply with detailed information.but when i am running the same i am getting NoClassDefFoundError.tried found root found that there is jar file missing (selenium-server-version.jar) added the same still i am getting following error.2016/06/21 23:23:36 ERROR - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Test failed! java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
 at com.blazemeter.jmeter.webdriver.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverConfig.createBrowser(PhantomJSDriverConfig.java:77)
 at com.blazemeter.jmeter.webdriver.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverConfig.threadStarted(PhantomJSDriverConfi

Comment: Perhaps your WebDriver Sampler plugin installation is corrupt. Try installing it using [Plugin Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri now it is executing but WebDriverSampler does not returning any values2016/06/22 14:11:38 INFO  - com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler: {}.is there any thing i am missing.For the Phantomjs Driver config path to Phantomjs Executables /Users/Users9949/Documents/softwares/phantomjs-1.9.7-macosx/bin/phantomjs please help me on this

Comment: Tried with Phantomjs version 2.1.1 it is working fine.Thanks so Much Dmitri.one More help please point me where can i get WebDriver sampler scripting examples to under more.

Comment: I am interested in domload and windowload tried to iterate through(tried both lenght and size()) the timings array.but it is throwing following error.2016/06/23 20:07:54 ERROR - com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EvaluatorException: Java class "com.google.common.collect.Maps$TransformedEntriesMap" has no public instance field or method named "0". (<Unknown source>#8) in <Unknown source> at line number 8 
please help on this..