# EvaluatorException while Iterating through Performance Timings in ClientSide

Tags: performance, jmeter, phantomjs, performance-testing

I am interested in domload and windowload tried to iterate through(tried both length and size()) the timings array. But it is throwing following **error**.

> 2016/06/23 20:07:54 ERROR -
>   com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler:
>   sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EvaluatorException: Java class
>   "com.google.common.collect.Maps$TransformedEntriesMap" has no public
>   instance field or method named "0". (#8) in  at line number 8

For more details please refer here [Collecting client side Performance Metrics from Phantomjs through Jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37922398/collecting-client-side-performance-metrics-from-phantomjs-through-jmeter)

Comment: Tried the for loop but still did not work
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
var urls= "http://www.google.com"
WDS.browser.get(urls)
for (var key in timings) throwing following Exception   ERROR - com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function hasOwnProperty in object

Comment: Btw, your title looks much more as a tag cloud, as a question.